# How does a static member in a TensorFlow OpKernel behave?

Tags: tensorflow

Specifically, if I have an Op inheriting from OpKernel, and inside this I have some private member declared `static`. Am I safe to assume that all instantiations of this kernel will access the same static member? Are all kernels placed on the same machine/worker (possibly different CPUs) in the same address space / process? Obviously, this would not apply to kernels mapped to separate machines in a distributed setting. E.g.

```
class MyOpKernel : public OpKernel {
  public:
    explicit MyOpKernel(OpKernelConstruction* ctx) : OpKernel(ctx) {
      if (!BigRODataObject)
        BigRODataObject = some_init_func();
    }

    void Compute( ... ) { // uses BigRODataObject }

  private:
    static BRODOType* BigRODataObject = null; 
};
```

Finally, when implementing an OpKernel, is there a better way than `static` to share a chunk of read-only data in memory between OpKernels of the same type? The data is too large to house multiple copies in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `static` member of a `tensorflow::OpKernel` is shared between all instances of that kernel in the same process. If you are running a single TensorFlow process, then all instances (including instances assigned to CPU or GPU, and instances from different sessions) will share the same `static` member.

Using a `static` member does not handle destruction when the session is closed and doesn't permit different objects in different sessions, so I wouldn't recommend this style; however the alternative is a bit more complicated. For shared state, we typically use the [`ResourceMgr`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/resource_mgr.h) (via [`OpKernelContext::resource_manager()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7022c01ac7282eed90db6b2c52195819264bc146/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h#L854)) to store objects. The typical implementation uses "constructor" op that instantiates the object on first use, owns it, and outputs a (string) handle. Users of the shared state take a data dependency on the handle, and look it up in the `ResourceMgr` to access the object. The object is then deleted when the "constructor" op is deleted. This is the approach used for stateful ops like `tf.Variable`, `tf.FIFOQueue`, etc.

Comment: Fantastic, this is the info I was looking for. Thanks!